# Presence information of Publishers in PubSub

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd, strophe

**Setup:**
I have setup a pubsub service wherein the publishers publish geolocation data at regular intervals.

The subscribers receive the location data of the publishers.

The subscribers are not presence subscribed, in the sense, the subscribers are not in the publishers rosters.

**Problem:**
The subscribers need to know the presence status of publishers.

Is there a way for the subscribers to know the presence status of publishers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since there is no direct relationship between subscribers and publishers, which is typical of any pubsub design.  To accomplish this the subscribers would need to know who the publishers are, which is not a good generic pubsub design.

It sounds like what you actually want is [PEP (Personal Eventing Protocol)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html), which is a subset of pubsub.  In this case, the subscribers are subscribing to nodes belonging to the actual user they are interested in.  If they are subscribed to the users presence, they automatically have access to the users nodes.

**NOTE**: I have recently found out that the newer version of the spec does in fact support an attribute that identifies the publisher.  Thus making it feasible to get their presence, but you would still have to subscribe or query for it.

Comment: PEP might not be feasible as, in my app the Subscribers do not know who the Publishers are. So can't subscribe to their presence.